Resources for probabilistic game theory
Can you suggest books/papers (or a collection of challenging problems) on game theory that is heavily probabilistic in nature?
I have a Quant trader interview coming up at Jane Street, and while my preparation of probabilities was thorough, I feel that being comfortable and familiar with traditional methods in the field will increase the chances of acing the interview. Any help is appreciated.
To be More Specific: In some games, I find it hard to come up with optimal strategies, though calculating the probabilities of a given strategy is not a challenge to me. So an ideal reference is one that discusses the different types of strategies employed in such games.
P.S. I've gone through most known books such as the green book (practical guide to quant finance interviews), Mark Joshi, etc. But they don't have satisfactory sections for probabilities and games.

In most games, it is hard (in particular, PPAD-complete https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPAD_(complexity)) for even a computer to come up with optimal strategies, so you're in good company.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8adJn_KQO0&list=PLEGCF-WLh2RJBqmxvZ0_ie-mleCFhi2N4&index=20 is a more detailed explanation of why being able to find mixed strategy Nash Equilibria in arbitrary games is too lofty a goal, despite one or more being guaranteed to exist.
